# Can't find users logged in with notty via the who command

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I was curious if anyone had any ideas why when I run `who` and `who --all`, I still cannot see users logged in under `notty`?

See below:

```
[cbennett@lstn ~]$ who --all
           system boot  2016-04-25 09:20
           run-level 3  2016-04-25 09:20
LOGIN      ttyS0        2016-04-25 09:20              1997 id=tyS0
LOGIN      tty1         2016-04-25 09:22              2281 id=tty1
           pts/0        2016-04-25 10:30              2057 id=ts/0  term=0 exit=0
cbennett + pts/1        2016-04-25 09:28 05:13        2607 (redacted)
kbennett + pts/8        2016-04-25 15:57 00:04       20513 (redacted)
cbennett + pts/9        2016-04-25 15:53   .         19733 (redacted)
           pts/10       2016-04-25 16:00             20980 id=s/10  term=0 exit=0
[cbennett@lstn ~]$ ps aux | grep kbennett | grep '@'
kbennett 17373  0.0  0.5 151628  5472 ?        S    15:37   0:00 sshd: kbennett@notty
kbennett 20517  0.0  0.4 151628  4164 ?        S    15:57   0:00 sshd: kbennett@pts/8
[cbennett@lstn ~]$
```

As an example, I can run the following:

```
ssh example.com sleep 300
```

And now my ssh connection that's open to `example.com` for 300 seconds won't show up under the `who` command, yet it does under `ps` with `@notty`.

What gives?

Comment: [Related](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92560/list-all-connected-ssh-sessions). tl;dr there is no way except explicit `ps` or `netstat`.